# Is there an iPod touch voice control app that can play music offline?

Tags: ios, applications, ipod-touch, music

I recently bought a 5th generation iPod touch, but was dismayed to learn that I can't use Siri to play music in my car because it doesn't work offline. Is there a voice control app that I can use to choose songs without a wifi connection?

Comment: If your phone is with you (you have iPhone tagged), create a personal hotspot with it, and use that to get your iPod the wifi connection it needs.

Comment: @Tyson Unfortunately, I don't, I just tagged it because the iPod touch uses the same apps as the iPhone. Should I take it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to sacrifice Siri for the ability to control your music with your voice, you could turn off Siri in Settings>General>Siri, which'll make your iPod respond to a held-down Home button with the classic Voice Control interface instead. A Google search is telling me that that one works offline!

For more information about non-Siri Voice Control, [check out Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201936). Here's what it says about music playback:

> - You can play all songs in an album, playlist, or by an artist. The device won't recognize commands to play a particular song.
> - If you can't get the device to recognize the album or artist name, try telling it to play a playlist.
> - If an artist has "The" in the name, say it.

Comment: Hmmmm..... that might work as a quick fix for me, but it's pretty unfortunate that you can't select a particular song. I know there's several voice control apps like Vokul, but I can't seem to confirm if any work offline.

Comment: @pocketlint You could always make one-song playlists.

Comment: Maybe, but then I have to think ahead to make playlists for each song, and I've got a pretty big library. Still, your solution is the best I've found, so thank you!